# How can I get the current OU with a PowerShell login script?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I am setting up a Terminal Server 2008 which will be used by different client organisations, each with multiple individual user accounts.
I would like each client organisation to have a drive mapped to 
\server\clients\

Their OU name is also their client name, so I would like to be able to find their current OU and then use it for the mapping command.
The OUs are hierarchicals, so it is the bottom-most OU name I need.

**Example**
    OU:
       Dedicated Clients\AjaxCorp

Should get a drive mapped to
    \\server1\shares\AjaxCorp

Any suggestions on how I can get the OU? I am sure it must be easy, I just haven't figured it out...

I did find information about how to do this with VB script, but as it is a whole new environment I thought it would be nice to use PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out how to get the OU from http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/pstips/dec07/pstip1207.mspx and thought I would share the results.
The code to get the OUs is this:

```
$strName = $env:username
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$strName))"

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

$objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
$objUser = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
$objUser.memberOf
```

However, I then had a realisation that using the OU would be fraught with difficulty as a user may be a member of multiple OU's. I therefore decided to use the Company field in the User object. From the same code above I can do

```
$strCompany = $objUser.Company
```

And then do my drive mapping.

This answers my original question, but just for interest I should mention that I then decided not to use PowerShell for the logon script after all: It is just too painful to deploy; You can't just put a .ps1 file in the Group Policy, you have to explicitly call Powershell.exe from a cmd file. So, I rewrote my script in vbscript in a few minutes and regretted that I hadn't started with that :)

Comment: A user object can only reside in one OU.

Answer (score 7):

This will get you the LDAP path to the current computer:

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry  
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=" + $env:computername + "))"

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher  
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain  
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

$strPath = $objSearcher.FindOne().Path
```

From the result in $strPath, you should be able to build a network path to the share you need.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for this, it did point me in the right direction. However, I was after the user and the OU of the user, not the computer. As it happens, your solution just needed a few tweaks to be what I was after so thanks!

Comment: My fault, I understood you were after the OU of the **computer**... getting the user OU is quite similar, though.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to get the ou

$hostname = hostname

$hostnameobject = get-adcomputer $hostname

$ou = $hostnameobject.distinguishedname

Answer (score 1):

To actually return an object of type Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit of a User Object, use this:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $(($adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:USERNAME).DistinguishedName.SubString($adUser.DistinguishedName.IndexOf("OU=")))
```

The same can be accomplished for a computer:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $(($adComputer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:COMPUTERNAME).DistinguishedName.SubString($adComputer.DistinguishedName.IndexOf("OU=")))
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, I then had a realisation that using the OU would be fraught with difficulty as a user may be a member of multiple OU's

No. It can't.
Per defintion a user account can only reside at one place in AD.
Different users however, may have the same RDN.

Answer (score -1):

Find the DN of the User and parse it from that.

I'm not a Powershell expert, or even an amateur for that matter, but that's probably where I'd start.

Sorry I can't be of any more assistance than that, hopefully it's some food for thought.